# Data Structure that supports queue like operations and mode finding

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, hashtable

This was an interview question asked to me almost 3 years back and I was pondering about this a while back.

> Design a data structure that supports the following operations:
>   insert_back(), remove_front() and find_mode(). Best complexity
>   required.

The best solution I could think of was O(logn) for insertion and deletion and O(1) for mode. This is how I solved it: Keep a queue DS for handling which element is inserted and deleted. 
Also keep an array which is max heap ordered and a hash table. 
The hashtable contains an integer key and an index into the heap array location of that element. The heap array contains an ordered pair (count,element) and is ordered on the count property.

Insertion : Insert the element into the queue. Find the location of the heap array index from the hashtable. If none exists, then add the element to the heap and heapify upwards. Then add the final location into the hashtable. Increment the count in that location and heapify upwards or downwards as needed to restore the heap property.

Deletion : Remove element from the head of the queue. From the hash table, find a location in the heap array index. Decrement the count in the heap and reheapify upward or downwards as needed to restore the heap property.

Find Mode: The element at the head of the array heap (getMax()) will give us the mode.

Can someone please suggest something better. The only optimization I could think of was using a Fibonacci heap but I am not sure if that is a good fit in this problem.

Comment: What you are describing is a `Deque` and it is pretty standard.

Comment: But how does a deque (which I presume is a double ended queue) keeps track of the element that has occurred maximum times in the array? Any links would be helpful.Thank you for your prompt answer

Comment: Ahhhh, I apologise. I overlooked the `Find_Mode` aspect of the requirements. I should say the structure of what you describe is [`Deque`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue#Complexity). You can see that all operations in the basic implementation are O(1) - however, find is not one of them... Sorry to waste your time here.

Comment: Readin again, I would implement a basic `Deque` class, here all core operations (`PushFront/Back`, `PopFront/Back` and extending the array size will be O(1). Then to this class (as I think you are saying above) I would implement a `Find` which merely loops over the entries of the `Deque`, this will be O(n). If you want quicker you might have to look into using a [Red-Black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) of some sort...

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a solution with `O(1)` for all operations.

You need a deque, and two hashtables.

The first one is a linked hashtable, where for each `element` you store its `count`, the `next` element in count order and a `previous` element in count order. Then you can look the next and previous element's entries in that hashtable in a constant time. For this hashtable you also keep and update the element with the largest count. (`element -> count, next_element, previous_element`)

In the second hashtable for each distinct number of elements, you store the elements with that count in the start and in the end of the range in the first hashtable. Note that the size of this hashtable will be less than `n` (it's `O(sqrt(n))`, I think). (`count -> (first_element, last_element)`)

Basically, when you add an element to or remove an element from the deque, you can find its new position in the first hashtable by analyzing its `next` and `previous` elements, and the values for the old and new count in the second hashtable in constant time. You can remove and add elements in the first hashtable in constant time, using algorithms for linked lists. You can also update the second hashtable and the element with the maximum count in constant time as well.

I'll try writing pseudocode if needed, but it seems to be quite complex with many special cases.

Comment: I agree with this answer because this is the one I proposed to my interviewer and it comes more naturally. However you have said the same thing my interviewer also said that is "it is difficult to code this and there *might* be some corner cases where it might not work". Hence I thought of this easier to implement albeit slower solution.

Comment: I think it _will_ work in all cases, but, yes, it may be really tricky to code and thus it should be tested very thoroughly.

Comment: I don't get it: when a value occurs multiple times, does it occur once or multiple times in your first hash table? I would think multiple times because next and previous are different for different copies, but then you have to update the counts of all copies when a new one is added, which is potentially O(N).

Comment: Sorry for late comment. It occurs only once. For example the queue is ('a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'c'). Then the first hashtable is ('a'->(1, 'c', Null), 'b'->(3, Null, 'c'), 'c'->(2, 'b', 'a'))